# Creating Client Side Notification without Push Tokens

Tags: android, push-notification

From my understanding if the user does not run the app for a long period of time the push token expires, and the user will not be reachable by push notifications. I am wondering if it's possible to schedule an AlarmManager lets say 10 days in the future when the user first runs the app and then on that day it will pull notifications from the server side.

Comment: i've never seen anything about the registration expiring. can you post a link that tells you that?

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications in android are stored up to [4 weeks by default](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/adv.html). That should be sufficient for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to *run* the app. The whole idea of a *push* service is that you don't need to *poll*. You should have a receiver registered in your app  with an action in the intent filter:

```
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
```

so that as long as you turn your phone on at least once during the default 4 week period, you will get the GCM message. This is all explained in the developer guide.